# Need to do a match on a value with partial name of textfield with jquery and return results

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I currently have a form set up where a user enters numbers, and based on the number entered, through jquery, a series of textboxes are displayed.

The code for the textbox display is as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{

ch.innerHTML = ch.innerHTML +"<div style='width:120px;float:left;'>Left    
Slide (size 6):</div><div style='float:left;width:100px;'> <input 
type='text' class='txt' style='width:80px;margin-right:10px;font-size:14px !
important;' name='six"+ i+"'></div>";

}
```

(there are several, from this example size 6, up through size 10.)

The jquery basically goes through and selects the value of all of the input textboxes, joins them and adds them to a hidden field on the form, which then gets submitted to the backend.

(I have ONLY one field to work with, and lots of information to pass through the one field.)

The code that does this part is as follows:

```
$(function() {
        $("#shineon").click(function(event) {               
            var data = [];

            var form = $("form :input[type=text]");



            $.each(form, function(e, textBox) {


                if (e > 0) {
data.push($.trim(textBox.value));
 }

            });


            $("#mybond").val(data.join(" "));


        });
    });
```

What this returns is almost exactly what I need, the value of all textboxes that were dynamically generated.

It returns the input as follows:

```
textone texttwo textthree textfour
```

However, I really need to join them in a more specific way - so that I capture all the values, but then based on a partial name match ("six") where my textfields are named as:  six1 six2 six3 and so on...

so that my input return looks like this:

```
 six1 - textone texttwo
 six2 - textone texttwo
 six3 - textone texttwo
```

Is there a way to accomplish this easily without destroying the code I have already written, which works perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `name` attribute from the element and concatenate it with the value:

```
data.push($.trim(textBox.getAttribute('name') + textBox.value));
```

Comment: This could work, but I won't know the names exactly, I will just know partial names - because it is dependent on the user input, which is unknown - so it could be that I need to get:

six1
six2
six3

or I could need to get six1, six2, six3, six4, six5, six6, six7 -

Comment: @ForeverDita do you want to get the `name` of the `input` with its corresponding `value`?

Comment: Yes, I want to loop through the inputs with a partial name match since I won't know if there are 2 or 10 or 15 - then I want to get the value but in a way that I can dump into a hidden field - I am doing this right now with the code I have above, but the results come back as space separated - what I would like to do is make it so that each of the results in a partial name match (i.e. six1, six2, six3) come back on one line, then the next line would give matches based on partial name seven (i.e. seven1, seven2, seven3, seven4, etc.) - does this make sense?

Comment: okay so if you want to create a new line each time, just add the new line character `\n`. write the code like this: `textBox.getAttribute('name') + textBox.value + '\n'`

Comment: I actually got it to work by using data.push(this.name); but I am accepting your answer because you put me on the right path and I would not have figured it out without your answer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out :)